# Как можно модифицировать код?

Tags: java, android

Нужно модифицировать код так, чтобы он так же работал для второго `TextView`. То есть выполнял все те же функции, но опять же повторюсь для второго `TextView`.
Вот сам код:

```
private TextView mDateDisplayStart;
    private TextView mDateDisplayEnd;
    private ImageButton mPickDateStart;
    private ImageButton mPickDateEnd;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDateDisplayStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DataStart);
        mPickDateStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showDatePicker);
        mPickDateStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplayStart.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1)
                .append("-").
                        append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear).append(" "));
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что вопрос состоял в том, чтобы 2 раздельные кнопки выполняли похожую функцию.

Вот как я бы это сделал:

*Layout*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.nov.datepickertest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateEnd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/showDateStartPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/showDateEndPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

*Activity*:

```
package com.blah.datepickertest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mDateDisplayStart;
    private TextView mDateDisplayEnd;
    private ImageButton mPickDateStart;
    private ImageButton mPickDateEnd;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDateDisplayStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateStart);
        mDateDisplayEnd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateEnd);
        mPickDateStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showDateStartPicker);
        mPickDateEnd = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showDateEndPicker);
        final Context context = this;
        mPickDateStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDatePicker dlg = new MyDatePicker(context);
                dlg.setTextView(mDateDisplayStart);
                dlg.show();
            }
        });
        mPickDateEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDatePicker dlg = new MyDatePicker(context);
                dlg.setTextView(mDateDisplayEnd);
                dlg.show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateDisplay(TextView tv, Calendar c) {
        tv.setText(new StringBuilder()
                .append(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                .append("-")
                .append(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                .append("-")
                .append(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
    }

    private class MyDatePicker extends DatePickerDialog {

        public MyDatePicker(Context context) {
            super(
                    context,
                    null,
                    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
        // Раскомментируй, если нужен такой конструктор
//      public MyDatePicker(Context context, @Nullable OnDateSetListener listener, int y, int m, int d) {
//          super(context, listener, y, m, d);
//      }

        private final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        private TextView tv = null;

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            // По мере изменения даты, обновляем Calendar:
            c.clear();
            c.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);

            // Если хочешь, чтобы дата менялась по мере ввода раскомментируй
            //if (tv!=null) updateDisplay(tv, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE && tv != null) {
                updateDisplay(tv, c);
            }
            super.onClick(dialog, which);
        }

        public void setTextView(TextView textView) {
            tv = textView;
        }
    }
}
```

Если раскомментировал, чтобы дата менялась по мере ввода, то тебе `onClick` вообще не нужен. Он для того, чтобы при выборе даты обновлять текст.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    String myDate = new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear).append(" ");
    mDateDisplayStart.setText(myDate);
    mDateDisplayEnd.setText(myDate);
}
```